# VBA: Why isn't my FOR loop returning anything?

Tags: ms-access, vba

The *overall* goal is to return the *characters* in between the commas and use each of them in another piece of code. If anyone knows a more optimal way of doing this, please let me know.

**The problem:**

I am trying to find the positions of the commas in the string.

**The string:**

```
Dim st As String
st = "1642377,001642381,010301642379"
```

**My attempt:**

```
For pos = 1 To Len(st)

     If Mid(st, pos, 1) = "," Then

         MsgBox ("Position of comma:" & pos)

     End If

 Next
```

**Currently returning:**

The code doesn't return anything. The `If` condition isn't returning true.

**Expected result:**

A `MsgBox` should pop up twice, showing the position of the comma each time.

Comment: Someone gave you a better way of doing this, but I'm guessing that your loop isn't running at all....Your code shows `For pos = 1 to len(st)`, but what is `st`?  You don't show how it's been declared or how long it is.....If you step through the the code you should be able to see what is happening.

Comment: @OpiesDad woops, sorry. `st` is simply the string.

Comment: If you want to find out why your loop isn't working, post a full sub with declarations and assignments. See [mcve]. Use [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) if you don't use it yet. -- Most probably, you will find the problem yourself while doing that.

Comment: @Andre This was the entire sub. And I have Option Explicit at the top.

Comment: With what you've said, the code you have provided will not run.  For 1, you stated that you have `Option Explicit`, but you have not declared `st` or `pos`, therefore, you must at least have a `Dim` statement you have not shown us.  For 2, the line `st = 1642377,001642381,010301642379` will not work regardless of what you have declared `st` to be because if it is a string, then it would need `"` around the number and if you don't have the `"` then the line you have provided will error out.  As Andre stated, if you want to know why the loop isn't working, you need to provide the COMPLETE code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the split function. It returns a string array

```
Dim parts() As String, p As Variant

parts = Split("1642377,001642381,010301642379", ",")
For Each p In parts
    Debug.Print p
Next
```

prints

```
1642377
001642381
010301642379
```

---

You are using 2 different values: `st` and `Me.Text585.Value`. Did you mean to use `st` in the two places? If I do so, the code works and it returns the positions 8 and 18.

Comment: `st` and `Me.Text585.Value` are the same thing, sorry about that. I will edit.